composer package with repo VCS not working
I have a fork repo in composer.json, but composer keep getting last release from forked one (1.1.4) instead of mine (1.1.6) from VCS.
If I do: composer show -a kalyabin/yii2-select-google-map-location -vv
I get:
Running cache garbage collection
Reading composer.json of fisciences/yii2-select-google-map-location (1.1.6)
Importing tag 1.1.6 (1.1.6.0)
Reading composer.json of fisciences/yii2-select-google-map-location (1.1.5)
Importing tag 1.1.5 (1.1.5.0)
Reading composer.json of fisciences/yii2-select-google-map-location (master)
Importing branch master (dev-master)
Reading composer.json of fisciences/yii2-select-google-map-location (custom)
Importing branch custom (dev-custom)
Reading composer.json of ruskid/yii2-csv-importer (1.1.3)
Importing tag 1.1.3 (1.1.3.0)
Reading composer.json of ruskid/yii2-csv-importer (1.1.2)
Importing tag 1.1.2 (1.1.2.0)
Reading composer.json of ruskid/yii2-csv-importer (1.1.1)
Importing tag 1.1.1 (1.1.1.0)
Reading composer.json of ruskid/yii2-csv-importer (1.1.0)
Importing tag 1.1.0 (1.1.0.0)
Reading composer.json of ruskid/yii2-csv-importer (master)
Importing branch master (dev-master)
name     : kalyabin/yii2-select-google-map-location
descrip. : Yii2 widget to select location at map and choose map coordinates
keywords : framework, map, location, widgets, yii2, input widget
versions : dev-master, * 1.1.4, 1.1.3, 1.1.2, 1.1.1, 1.1.0, 1.0.x-dev, 1.0.0
released : 2018-06-26, 6 years ago
type     : package
license  : BSD 3-Clause "New" or "Revised" License (BSD-3-Clause) (OSI approved) https://spdx.org/licenses/BSD-3-Clause.html#licenseText
homepage : 
source   : [git] https://github.com/kalyabin/yii2-select-google-map-location.git ed34105d783f6db07bd22d0423c8ccb5c7782627
dist     : [zip] https://api.github.com/repos/kalyabin/yii2-select-google-map-location/zipball/ed34105d783f6db07bd22d0423c8ccb5c7782627 ed34105d783f6db07bd22d0423c8ccb5c7782627
path     : /Users/martinpineault/PhpstormProjects/SportsLeagues/vendor/kalyabin/yii2-select-google-map-location
names    : kalyabin/yii2-select-google-map-location

support
issues : https://github.com/kalyabin/yii2-select-google-map-location/issues
source : https://github.com/kalyabin/yii2-select-google-map-location/tree/master

autoload
psr-4
kalyabin\maplocation\ => .

requires
php >=5.4.0
yiisoft/yii2 2.*

So COMPOSER see everything.
Here my composer.json:
    "require": {
        ...
        "kalyabin/yii2-select-google-map-location": "*",
        ...
    },
    ...
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/fiSCIENCES/yii2-select-google-map-location"
        },
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/fiSCIENCES/yii2-csv-importer"
        },
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://asset-packagist.org"
        }
    ]
}

Strangely, the second repo is working fine for another similar package.
Thank you,

Finaly,
I had changed the name in composer.json of my fork from:
"name": "kalyabin/yii2-select-google-map-location",
to:
"name": "fisciences/yii2-select-google-map-location",
by mistake.
Leaving it to:
"name": "kalyabin/yii2-select-google-map-location",
resolved the problem.
